# Minimum Number of Clues for Unsolvable Sudoku

Tags: puzzle, sudoku

I am going to make a distinction between "unsolvable" and "invalid" Sudoku. A Sudoku is unsolvable if there is no way to fill in all the spaces without violating one of the rules of Sudoku. An Sudoku is invalid if the clues given violate one of the rules of Sudoku.

The minimum number of clues needed for a invalid Sudoku is obviously 2. However, I cannot figure how what is the minimum number of clues needed for an unsolvable Sudoku. I found an unsolvable Sudoku with 5 clues (shown below), but I cannot figure out how to proceed for here.

[image]

Comment: But invalid Sudoku's are unsolvable??? I'm not sure I understand the distinction.

Comment: FYI, a somewhat related issue of the minimum number of Sodoku clues to produce a unique answer is $17$, e.g., see [Mathematicians Solve Minimum Sudoku Problem](https://www.technologyreview.com/2012/01/06/188520/mathematicians-solve-minimum-sudoku-problem/).

Comment: Just to be clear, your title is wrong, no?  Using your definitions, the minimal number for an *invalid* Sudoku is clearly $2$ (just put two $1's$ in a column or whatever), as you remark.  It's the minimal *unsolvable* Sudoku you want.

Comment: I am not sure I understand this, but I guess what meant is that the given entries do not exhibit a violation (there is not already a duplicate), but the Sudoku is nevertheless unsolvable. My first intuition is that $4$ entries are not sufficient, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Maybe slightly related, but I would not be surprised if there would be an easy proof that for the given problem , the miniuzm is $5$ , whereas the $17$ was found, if I am informed right, only be exhaustive search.

Comment: Lulu, you are correct and I messed up the title. I have edited the question to fix it.

Comment: Please improve the Q. It is nice but interpretable

Comment: related: https://www.quora.com/Does-every-validly-posed-Sudoku-have-at-least-one-solution-If-not-what-is-the-minimum-number-of-givens-for-it-to-be-unsolvable